# Bash loop to create indexed merged files

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have 24 pairs of these  files (24 files `output.chr1 to 24_.vcf.gz` and 24 files `Analysis.chr1 to 24_.output.vcf.gz`). I am trying to merge these corresponding pairs to create `merged_file_.chr1 to 24_.vcf.gz` files. How can I form such loop in bash script to use this following command?

```
vcf-merge output.chr1.vcf.gz Analysis.chr1.output.vcf.gz | \
  bgzip -c > ../dir_destination/merged_file_.chr1.vcf.gz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for n in {1..24}; do
  vcf-merge output.chr$n.vcf.gz Analysis.chr$n.output.vcf.gz | \
    bgzip -c > ../dir_destination/merged_file_.chr$n.vcf.gz
done
```